# ContactsManager missing methods?

Tags: codenameone

I am wondering why the methods update or link are missing from ContactsManager.  Also, how to deal with contact groups?  I feel I'm missing something since those could serve a few use cases.

Thanks for your help.

E

Answer (score 0):

This class was built to represent common grounds between contact API's that are implemented very differently between the OS's. There are concepts in Google/Apple that have no equivalent in the corresponding OS so we kept the API at the lowest common denominator.

If you want a more thorough API you can build a cn1lib and access the respective contacts API's directly.

Comment: Thanks, Shai.  I must admit I was that lazy guy hoping to find that cn1lib somewhere...

Comment: How would you simplify this functionality with a cn1lib?